# JSON Array not Binding to MVC Model

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a list of json data to the controller via a AJAX call.
The String arrays "LandPhone, Mobile and Email"  are getting null  in the controller. Actually there is some values.

**Main Model**

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public string ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string TINNo { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerAddressModel> Address { get; set; }

}
```

**Sub Model**

```
public class CustomerAddressModel
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string[] LandPhone { get; set; }
    public string[] Mobile { get; set; }
    public string[] Email { get; set; }

}
```

**AJAX Call**

```
function get() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/temp/Customer',
    data: { "ReferenceId": "", "FirstName": "", "MiddleName": "", "LastName": "", "TINNo": "", "CurrencyId": 0,
            "Address": [{
                "AddressLine1": "", "AddressLine2": "", "AddressLine3": "", "ZipCode": 0, "District": "", "State": "", "Country": "",
                "LandPhone": ["123"],
                "Mobile": ["1234567890", "9876543210"],
                "Email": ["a@b.com", "b@c.com"]
            }]
     },
    dataType: "json",
    //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**In the Controller Method Data getting like this**

[image: In the Controller Method Data getting like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` option and also stringify the data

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Customer", "temp")', // don't hard code
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    data: JSON.stringify({ "ReferenceId": ..... "Address": [{ "AddressLine1": "" ... }]}),
    ....
```

Comment: In my case, I also had to add `[FromBody]` to the controller method. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0.